# 'ExpandableListAdapter' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, expandablelistview

I was working on the tutorial at http://javapapers.com/android/android-expandable-listview/.

I was working on the MainActivity.java section, and I got this error:

'ExpandableListAdapter' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

How can I fix this?

Comment: Create your own Adapter and extends that ExpandableListAdapter. Don't forget to implement parent's abstract methods (IDE will show you errors)

Comment: ... or extend `BAseExpandableListAdapter`, it has some of the abstract methods already implemented, but you'll need to implement the basic ones.

Comment: What kind of parameter is the 'this', in the ExpandableListAdapter constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename the Adapter **`ExpandableListAdapter's`** this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little old question but this answer might help to those facing similar issue. Essentially, you are getting that error as ExpandableListAdapter is an abstract class. To get rid of it implement your own Adapter. You might refer to following post to understand how it can be done - http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/. Hope this helps. Thanks.